# Have PDF text read out loud

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, accessibility, text-to-speech, foxit-reader

I need a program that can read the text in PDF documents out loud, and have basic functionality such as pause/resume, change speed of reading, and it **must highlight** the word or sentence being red. I've tried Foxit reader but it seems insufficient, for example you can't even [choose where to start reading](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-684360-how-to-make-foxit-reader-to-read-aloud-just-one-paragraph). I also tried Adobe Reader, view->enable read out loud, view->read this page only - but nothing happened. Are there any other programs better suited for the job? I want something like Kurzweil 3000 but don't want to spend $1000.

Comment: Windows narrator can do everything except highlighting...but you need highlighting...so no use

Comment: pdf-to-text is needed first: see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/52040/is-there-a-better-pdf-to-text-converter-than-pdftotext/344080#344080 (not only on linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Read Out Loud** is a **Text-to-Speech** (TTS) tool that is built into **Adobe Reader 6.0**. It reads text contained within a document window. This functionality is different from “screen reader” technology, which not only reads text within a document but also lets visually impaired users navigate their computer and access menu items, dialog boxes, or message boxes.

To use **Read Out Loud**, you will need:

- **Adobe Reader 6.0** or later
- The **Text-to-Speech** engine installed in the operating system

http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/reader6/sec2.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I tried this and it didn't work. How do I check to see if the text-to-speech engine is installed?

Comment: What operating system do you have?

Comment: Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Great; by default **Text-To-Speech** engine is turned on in Windows and it can be configured through _Speech properties_ in **Control panel.** (In Windows 7, use **Control Panel** > **Speech Recognition** > **Select Text-To-Speech** on the left pane.) Use the **Preview** button to make sure you can hear Microsoft Anna, and that **TTS** is _ON_.

Comment: Once you have verified that **TTS** is _ON_ and you can hear it, open your PDF in **Adobe Reader** 6.0 or above.  Use **Edit Menu** > **Preferences**. In the **Category** list, chose **Reading**.Under the **Readout loud** group box, **Use default voice** check box would be checked by default. Unchecking this would enable the selection of different voices.  Select the voice of your choice in the drop down and click **OK**.  Adjust the **volume** and the **reading order.**

Each voice listed in the preference Drop down is a speech engine from operating system.

Comment: Thanks I got it working, though I really had hopped for a program with more control, for example user decides where to start reading as Reader only reads entire page.

Comment: hmm.. there is a way using Nircmd.exe to read the text on the clipboard.  Would that work at all?

Comment: I could try it sure

Comment: How do you get Adobe Reader to highlight the word/sentence being read?